# Unable to make ULPI works with STM32F446

Tags: stm32, embedded, usb-device

I am using a USB3300 chip as an external HS 480Mbit/s USB PHY  with STM32F446 MCU. Using CubeMX to generate code and add USB CDC Middleware. As I connect the USB Cable from the PC to the USB3300 chip no COM port is detected.

Didn't find any official document related ULPI Interface or any example. I need your help to resolve this issue.

I have attached the waveforms of CLK(Yellow), DIR(Purple), NXT(Blue), STP(Green). This time I used a 10x probe and my scope is 100MHz. Here before CLK the state of DIR is High and after CLK the state of DIR is Low, but the state of STP is the same HIGH as it should also go Low after the DIR pin goes Low according to the document ULPI Design Guide https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/en562704.pdf.

If I disconnect the CLK Pin my code hangs on while loop:-

/**

- @brief  Reset the USB Core (needed after USB clock settings change)
- @param  USBx  Selected device
- @retval HAL status
  */
  static HAL_StatusTypeDef USB_CoreReset(USB_OTG_GlobalTypeDef *USBx)
  {
  __IO uint32_t count = 0U;

/* Wait for AHB master IDLE state. */
do
{
count++;

```
if (count > HAL_USB_TIMEOUT)
{
  return HAL_TIMEOUT;
}
```

} while ((USBx->GRSTCTL & USB_OTG_GRSTCTL_AHBIDL) == 0U);

/* Core Soft Reset */
count = 0U;
USBx->GRSTCTL |= USB_OTG_GRSTCTL_CSRST;

do
{
count++;

```
if (count > HAL_USB_TIMEOUT)
{
  return HAL_TIMEOUT;
}
```

} while ((USBx->GRSTCTL & USB_OTG_GRSTCTL_CSRST) == USB_OTG_GRSTCTL_CSRST);

return HAL_OK;
}

[image: STM32CubeIDE Configuration]
[image: Waveforms]
[image: ULPI Design Guideline]

Comment: Please check if you've configured the USB peripheral correctly in CubeMX, including clock settings, pin assignments, and middleware configuration for USB CDC.